# System Call receiving garbage values

Tags: linux-kernel, system-calls

I have been trying to implement a system call that takes an int and a long value as parameters and returns a long value.
In my user space I call it using

```
int x = 3; long y = 4;
syscall(335, x, y);
```

335 being the new system call I am implementing

Additionally in my system call, I have the following:

```
asmlinkage long sys_first(int x, long y)
{
printk("%d %ld\n", x, y);
....
}
```

The printed values in dmesg is showing garbage values instead of "3 4" which it should.

I did a strace and in the syscall_0x14f it is passing the correct values.

Where is the program going wrong?

Comment: Have you tried `syscall(335, (long)x, y);`?